# Python list comprehension logical into example

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'm studying list comprehension in Python and I came across this example:

```
vec = [[11, 21, 31],
[42, 52, 62],
[73, 83, 93]]
var=[vec[i][len(vec)-1-i] for i in range(len(vec))]
print(var)
```

I wanted to understand exactly the logic behind the line where is the list comprehension and why the code stop to iterate to i = 2 ? ( I saw in debug mode, but it's still not clear to me).
Then what exactly does it take into "len(vec)-1 -i ? I know that len(vec) -1 is final of my list, but why -i?

Comment: `len(vec)` equals 3, `range(3)` returns `0, 1, 2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why the code stop to iterate to i = 2 ? ( I saw in debug mode, but it's still not clear to me)

```
for i in range(len(vec))
```

What is `len(vec)`? `vec` is a list of lists. `len` gets only the outermost length. In this case, `3`.

Try `print(list(range(3))` to see what values of `i` you'll get. (Explanation: `range` upper bound is exclusive, so it will never get to 3.)

This ensures `vec[i]` never gets out of range.

> Then what exactly does it take into "len(vec)-1 -i ? I know that len(vec) -1 is final of my list, but why -i?

```
vec[i][len(vec)-1-i]
```

`vec[i]` fetches the current sub-list.

`len(vec)` is length of the outer list (3), `len(vec)-1` is the index of the last element, `i` goes from 0 to `len(vec)-1` (inclusive)

Let's analyse what values will `len(vec)-1-i` get for each i:

- i=0 => 2
- i=1 => 1
- i=2 => 0

We're basically "going back" with the index.

So we're getting `vec[0][2]`, `vec[1][1]`, `vec[2][0]`. That is, diagonal of the `vec`, from upper right to lower left.

Answer (score 0):

```
var=[vec[i][len(vec)-1-i] for i in range(len(vec))]
```

This line denotes list comprehension. Here you are running a for loop for `range(3)`, so it stops at `i=2` iterating as `0`, `1` and then `2`. `len(vec)-1 -i` produces `2`, `1`, `0`. You are accessing `vec[0][2]`, `vec[1][1]`, and then `vec[2][0]` through the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

I'll explain your code step by step :

```
# This creates a 2D matrix (a nested list as we say in Python).
vec = [[11, 21, 31],
       [42, 52, 62],
       [73, 83, 93]]

# To obtain all the elements of the counterdiagonal in the 2D matrix, we iterate with inital value of i set to `0`, then,   
# Possible values for i varaible will be 0,1,2. 
# Hence, vec[i][len(vec)-1-i] will select following elements:
# vec[0][2] = 31
# vec[1][1] = 52
# vec[2][0] = 73
# These elements will then be stored in a new list named var. Hence when you print var, you'll get : 
var=[vec[i][len(vec)-1-i] for i in range(len(vec))]
# Output : [31, 52, 73]
print(var)
```